# using static variable for realm database variable

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, realm, static-variables

Is this a better way to write realm access variables? I am using static variable because I notice that I only need 1 declaration of database connection for all realm queries in other class. But I am curious if this is still good at coding standards.

```
using Realms;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace RealmDatabase
{
    public class RealmDBAccessVariable
    {
        public static readonly string dbPath = 
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), 
            "default.realm");
        public static readonly RealmConfiguration config = new     RealmConfiguration(dbPath, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the singleton pattern that I use for a Realm instance that I use on  the UI Thread:

#### `Xamarin.Android`:

```
public sealed class UIRealm
{
    static Realms.Realm instance;
    public UIRealm(Activity activity, RealmConfiguration config)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                instance = Realms.Realm.GetInstance(config);
            });
        else
            throw new Exception("A Realm instance has already be created");
    }

    public static Realms.Realm Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                throw new Exception("Call new UIRealm(Activity, RealmConfiguration) first");
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Create a UIRealm() only once
new UIRealm(this, new RealmConfiguration("realm.db"));
~~~
var aState = new State();
aState.Name = "WA";
UIRealm.Instance.Manage(aState);
var washingtonState = UIRealm.Instance.All<State>().Where((state => state.Name == "WA"));
```

#### `Xamarin.Forms`:

```
public sealed class UIRealm
{
    static Realm instance;
    public UIRealm(RealmConfiguration config)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                instance = Realm.GetInstance(config);
            });
        else
            throw new Exception("A Realm instance has already be created");
    }

    public static Realm Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                throw new Exception("Call new UIRealm(RealmConfiguration) first");
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Create a UIRealm() only once
new UIRealm(new RealmConfiguration("realm.db"));
~~~
var aState = new State();
aState.Name = "WA";
UIRealm.Instance.Manage(aState);
var washingtonState = UIRealm.Instance.All<State>().Where((state => state.Name == "WA"));
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the usage sir :) i'm still trying to look at it since yesterday but I cannot understand it well :) but now I'll give it a try :)

Comment: I added a `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.Form` example as I use this on the UI thread and this enforces that the realm instance is created on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will most probably run into problems the moment you try to write to the Realm on a background thread, and you attempt to access the `realm` for this operation which you opened on the UI thread.

`static` is generally insufficient, ThreadLocal is what would achieve this in Java.

I'm also not sure why this object is a RealmObject.

Comment: sorry . realmobject there is not needed. I just transfered it to a realmobject class from it's original class that's why there is a RealmObject extension.

I also removed Realm realm there to make it as object in other class.
My intention is to make those 2 variable accessible to other class without instantiating it more than once. Is it still fine?

Comment: It's fine as long as you access it only on the same thread. Typically the UI Thread Realm instance is static, and others are local.

Comment: with dbPath and config stated as static. and Realm realm stated as local variable. It's still safe if I run a service like for sync right?

Comment: `with dbPath and config stated as static. and Realm realm stated as local variable.` yeah that works